# Yii2 Dropdown list without value attribute inside option element

Tags: php, yii2

I'm creating a year dropdown list using the following code:

```
<?php
$range = range(2016, 2026);
echo $form->field($model, 'year')->dropDownList($range)->label("Year");
?>
```

It outputs:

```
<select id="testform-year" class="form-control" name="TestForm[year]">
    <option value="0">2016</option>
    <option value="1">2017</option>
    <option value="2">2018</option>
    <option value="3">2019</option>
    <option value="4">2020</option>
    <option value="5">2021</option>
</select>
```

But I want the output without value attribute inside option, like:

```
<select id="testform-year" class="form-control" name="TestForm[year]">
    <option>2016</option>
    <option>2017</option>
    <option>2018</option>
    <option>2019</option>
    <option>2020</option>
    <option>2021</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why do you want without value attribute ?

Comment: Because when I submitting the form I get value 0 instead of 2016.

Comment: without value attribute, how would you know that which option is selected and submitted ?

Comment: Only want this in case of year dropdown, because I think, if value attribute is not defined the option text will be used as value, like we do in normal PHP. Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @alex If you want all option value as 0 ,than create dropdown list manually using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
This will create the dropdown wuth value as 2016 and not 0.

```
<?php
$range = range(2016, 2026);
echo $form->field($model, 'year')->dropDownList(array_combine($range, $range))->label("Year");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking for that solution. But is it possible to create dropdownlist without value attribute in Yii2.

Comment: It wont be of any use to you. You wont get any value after you submit the form.

Comment: Only want this in case of year dropdown, because I think, if value attribute is not defined the option text will be used as value, like we do in normal PHP. Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: That is incorrect. option text will not be used as value